# R : How to get a single element in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to get the first element from data.table

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(data.frame(prices=c(1.1,2.4,5.3),
                            dates = c(2011-01-04,2011-01-05,2011-01-03)))
dt
     date       value
 1: 2011-01-04   1.1
 2: 2011-01-05   2.4
 3: 2011-01-03   5.3
> dt[1,1]
[1] 1
> dt[1]
     date       value
 1: 2011-01-04   1.1
> dt[1][1]
     date       value
 1: 2011-01-04   1.1
```

I need to get the first date. I'm not sure what i'm missing here :(

Thanks a lot. I was bit confused with the output.

> dt[1, date]
>        [1] 2011-01-04
>        Levels: 2011-01-03 2011-01-04 2011-01-05 (any idea what levels mean?)

This also works st$date[1]. Implementation is same as data frame.

Comment: `data.table` objects do inherit from data.frames so you can use `$` but it will be much slower on larger jobs.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat for a single column retrieval `$` is going to be several orders of magnitude faster than `[.data.table` because of large overhead of the latter function

Comment: OP, that `data.frame()` bit is unneccessary

Comment: @eddi; That assertion about the relative speed of `$` versus `[`with data.table objects was very surprising. Generally one does not see the word "large overhead" adjacent to "data.table".

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat there is a lot of internal magic happening inside `[.data.table`, to make it do the wonders that it does, and that magic is costly. This is normally a non-issue as to see the overhead you have to run `[.data.table` in a large loop, but it does come up sometimes (most frequently when using `.SD`) and is **the** Achilles' heel of `data.table` imo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
dt[1, date]
```

One of the joys of using data.table's is that the expressions in the 'j' position get evaluated in the context of the existing named columns. No need to use `with()`.

Comment: thanks, I was bit confused with the output.> dt[1, date]
[1] 2011-01-04
Levels: 2011-01-03 2011-01-04 2011-01-05

Comment: Oh, then you have a factor column, but that was not clear from the print output.

Comment: Indeed its a factor column. I should read more on that. But I used st <- data.frame(prices=c(1.1,2.4,5.3),dates = c(2011-01-04,2011-01-05,2011-01-03)) to create the data frame. R automatically makes it a factor?

Comment: The data.frame function has a parameter named stringsAsFactors which is set to TRUE as the default value. You can suppress that in the call to data.frame by setting to FALSE. I do not think that data.table will coerce character vectors in the same manner.

Answer (score -3):

Try `dt[1,"date"]`

I'm assuming the output you are looking for is `2011-01-04`

or `dt[1,2]`

in data frames in R the first column of what look like integers are actual column names. Thus, if dt was a data frame `dt[1,1]` returns the name of the first row which is just `1`. I think something similar is happening here.

Comment: dt[1,"date"], I think

Comment: I don't think the quotes are going to help. And user6179 needs to understand that the question is not about dataframes.

Comment: yes,second expression is evaluated, here it returns "date value"

Comment: Oh, OK. Character elements somewhat trivially evaluate to themselves.